# Where can i edit CSS file in shopify

Tags: css, shopify

I just validated my site on `validator.w3.org` and one of the error was

```
Error: CSS: font-family: Parse Error.

From line 80, column 875; to line 80, column 877

-system, &#39;Helve
```

I am trying to find this line in shopify themes.liquid file and i couldn't find it. I tried searching the page with `Helve` input, then `-system` input and couldn't find anything. Where should i make this fix in shopify code?

==== Updating with style.scss.liquid file ===

The only reference to Hevetica Neue is on following lines. I don't know why this is creating HTML error

```
/*================ Typography Variables ================*/
{% if settings.type_base_family contains 'Google' %}
  {% assign type_base_parts = settings.type_base_family | split: '_' %}
  {% assign type_base_name = type_base_parts[1] %}
  {% capture base_family %}"{{ type_base_name | split: ':' | first | replace: '+', ' ' }}"{% if type_base_parts.last == 'serif' %}, serif {% else %}, "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
{% else %}
  {% assign base_family = settings.type_base_family %}
{% endif %}

{% if settings.type_accent_family contains 'Google' %}
  {% assign type_accent_parts = settings.type_accent_family | split: '_' %}
  {% assign type_accent_name = type_accent_parts[1] %}
  {% capture accent_family %}"{{ type_accent_name | split: ':' | first | replace: '+', ' ' }}"{% if type_accent_parts.last == 'serif' %}, serif {% else %}, "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
{% else %}
  {% assign accent_family = settings.type_accent_family %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you have an url or is the website on localhost?

Comment: Its not on the localhost.

Comment: Can you give the url to the webpage?

Comment: https://topoutdeals.com/ ... I updated my question too. &#38; was missing when i *quoted* the actual error

Answer (score 0):

The error which W3C valiator is throwing is coming from your header. If you open developer tools and search for `&#39;` you will find the following in your DOM.

[image]

Comment: that i see. but what i am trying to see is where can i fix it. i don't see a reference in theme.scss.liquid file.

Comment: I don't think it is in a scss file. My quess is this is in a header html file or someting like that.

Comment: I still couldn't find it :s